# @name matches in chat are not unique enough

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, reply

Okay, so I logged into the [chat site](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/third-place-chat-beta-preview/) a couple days ago and stayed for a few minutes.

Then today, I come back to it and discovered the "Events affecting you" page.

Here is the problem:

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/chatglitch.png

As you can see, many people posted stuff to me, but I wasn't there. But someone else with a similar name was: [George Stocker](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker).

So I'm guessing that it's showing me all of the comments made to him and not me.

Is this true? Can it be fixed?

Is this a problem on any of the other sites?

Comment: It's all about efficiency, now we can contact all Georges at once.  World Domination is just around the corner.

Comment: @Lance: I don't think that's the way to do it...

Comment: Yet another reason the "other" George needs to revert back to "Gortok".

Comment: Or you could become "Gored".

Comment: Who was in charge of keeping those two separated?!?

Comment: @Jon B blame @Jeff Atwood for the whole ,"Moving to my real name" bit.  Something about building your online brand. Yea, I drank that kool-aid.

Comment: It may help that the auto-complete is now working and friendly, and uses full name - so it is easier to enter @GeorgeEdison than it is to enter @George. That do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@name handling works similarly to SO comments at the moment. It looks at all people who have been active in the room, so it isn't *all* Georges on the site. It also *intentionally* still works after you've left the room for a while.

The system does support more granular naming, so @George-Stocker or @George-S will get addressed only to "other George".

Your thoughts on what we should do differently here? Maybe it ties in slightly with auto-complete....

---

With auto-complete now implemented, IMO this is no longer an issue. It is now easier to get right than wrong. And when it *is* wrong, it is wrong in the same way as SO comments.

Comment: well you might start, by behaving more like comments.. where @georgestocker or @georges is the correct way to uniquely address "George Stocker"

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, good idea. The more 'correct' usernames you accept the better.

Comment: why don't you just add a reply button to each message? then you could internally store the correct addressee. The [comment reply](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43055/greasemonkey-script-for-displaying-threaded-comments/46562#46562) greasemonkey script is already something I don't like to browse SOFU without...

Comment: sheepishly heads off to remove the dashes...

Comment: Facebook's @user uses autocomplete and seems to work fairly well. Wait... Jeff doesn't know where I live does he?

Answer (score 0):

See, I've avoided commenting in questions comment in just so we wouldn't have this happen on a Stack Overflow site.

Now it's going to the third-place as well? *Swell*.

Comment: Why does this happen anyway? Is this a known issue?

Comment: @George, @George: one of you is going to have to be killed. When is a good time for the arena death match?

Comment: @Ether: Dec 31 / 69 - 16:00

Comment: @Ether: Hmmm... looks like my SQL database reset that field...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting what you consider a "rather serious" bug -- I expected something like

> I entered a room and a message box popped up saying "PWNED!"

-- or would that be a *quite* serious bug?

Anyway:

@mentions are currently applied to anyone who has ever been in the room; in other words: Every George who has ever been in the Chat Feedback room will be considered "mentioned" when someone says "@George". This obviously won't scale quite well in the long run.

We do, however, want some more flexibility than @mentions in SO comments currently provide. The logistics of this aren't non-trivial, so we're still figuring this out.

Comment: No, if a message popped up saying "PWNED!" would not be serious.